# Given reflexive relations $R$ and $S$ on $X$, $R\cap S$ is reflexive

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Give a proof or counterexample.
>
> Given reflexive relations $R$ and $S$ on $X$, $R\cap S$ is reflexive.

This would be true, correct?

Comment: Please make the body of your post self-contained, instead of relying on the subject for key content.

Comment: Well, do you have a proof, or do you have a counterexample?

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_of_Reflexive_Relations_is_Reflexive

Answer (score 2):

If $R$ and $S$ are reflexive relations on a set $X$, then $(x,x)\in R$  and $(x,x)\in S$ for all $x\in X$, so $R\cap S$ is reflexive as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use proof by contradiction. Suppose that $R\cap S$ is not reflexive. Use definition of intersection to show a contradiction.